# How to add UIButton to IBOutletCollection prorammatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, iboutletcollection

I need to make a bunch of buttons from the code and add them in IBOutletConnection. 
I haven't been able to do that so far.
When I do it in storyboard, it works just fine, but I cannot add the button to a collection programmatically.
Here is my code:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton)NSMutableArray *buttonsArray;
```

.m

```
-(void)createButton
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button addTarget:self
               action:nil
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [self writeCloud:button];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(-50, 80, 90, 60);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [_buttonsArray addObject:button];
}
```

The error I get is at `[_buttonsArray addObject:button];` saying:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14559050'

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. If you aren't using interface builder, why are you trying to use IBOutletCollection? Why not just use a plain old array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the array is not mutable. You have specified this in the @property definition but that doesn't make it true (if the storyboard unarchive sets it to a non-mutable array).

After the view is loaded I guess you can say:

```
self.buttonsArray = [self.buttonsArray mutableCopy];
```

and then your code should work.

Comment: Wain, I have no idea how this works, but it worked. Can you explain a bit better, please. Why my array wasn't mutable if i declared it mutable in the first place?
thanks.

Comment: You declared the property as mutable, but you didn't set the value, the unarchiving process did, and it doesn't care that you said it should be mutable, it only knows how to use immutable objects. The change we made is to cheat a little and make a mutable version of it before you want to edit it.